# Raphaeljs IE8 setViewBox not working

Tags: internet-explorer-8, raphael, vml, viewbox

I use RaphaelJS for generate SVG. My SVG is 1024px width and height.
I use `setViewBox` because the div containing it is more small than 510px width and height.

With IE8 RaphaelJS produces VML but `setViewBox` is not working, the size of VML produced is 1024px.

How I can make that VML responsive?

```
paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("SVGDiv"));

paper.canvas.id = 'paper';
paper.setViewBox(0,0,1024,1024);
paper.setViewBox(0,0,1024,1024);
image = paper.image("",0,0, 1024, 1024);
text = paper.text(512, 512, '');
if( isIE() > 8 || isIE() == false){
    paper.setSize("100%","100%");
}
```

Comment: Your question title does not really hint to a problem, please change the title to a more descriptive line for your problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? It seems like there are some bugs in the recent versions of Raphael in the VML module, see for example [Raphael.js function getBBox give back NAN/NAN/NAN in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277052/raphael-js-function-getbbox-give-back-nan-nan-nan-in-ie8/39329259#39329259) which is tracable to some wonky code related to VML viewboxes. For me in 2.2.0 and 2.2.1 setViewBox doesn't zoom and the VML element event when set with % widths doesn't scale responsively

Comment: I use more VML so I have no solution
Sry