# Raphael.js function getBBox give back NAN/NAN/NAN in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, raphael

using Raphaël 2.1.4 - JavaScript Vector Library 
do something like that:

```
var textDummy = paper.text(50,500, 'hello world').attr({fill: 'transparent', 'font-size': 14});
var textBox = textDummy.getBBox();
```

with chrome and firefox everything is fine,
but in IE8 it give back NaN/NaN/NaN,
par exemple textBox.height is NaN.

how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in Rapahel 2.2.0 and 2.2.1, and using `._getBBox()` didn't fix it for me.

What did fix it for me is falling back to `.auxGetBBox()` if it's defined and regular `.getBBox()` doesn't work, like this:

```
var bbox = path.getBBox( );

// Workaround for apparent bug in Raphael's VML module's getBBox() override
if( isNaN( bbox.x ) && path.auxGetBBox ){
  bbox = path.auxGetBBox();
}
```

---

I don't have a fix for the underlying bug, but I have found the source of it.

In VML mode, Raphael takes the initial `getBBox()` function, saves it as `auxGetBBox()` on the element prototype, then replaces it with a function that appears to be broken.

It has calculations based on a variable defined as `var z = 1/this.paper._viewBoxShift.scale;`, which clearly expects _viewBoxShift.scale to be some factor of the scale of the current viewbox compared to the initial viewbox , but actually `_viewBoxShift.scale` is an object like this which appears to come from `paperproto.getSize()`:

`{ height: someNumber, width: someNumber }`

This is where all the `NaN`s are coming from. Cannae divide by an object.

So this workaround works fine if no zoom is applied using a viewbox, but may give incorrect results if a zoom has been applied (something I can't get to work at all in recent versions of raphael in VML mode, but that's a seperate question). Fixing *that* will involve digging deep into Raphael's VML module to pipe a proper zoom factor into this `z` variable.

Answer (score 2):

i found a workaround solution from [this answer to the question
"Raphael JS and Text positioning"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461866/568458.)

If i use `_getBBox()` instead of `getBBox()` everything is working in ie 8 also.

> _getBBox() is undocumented but used internally by Raphael itself, and it works!

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Raphael 2.2.0 - `path.getBBox()` in IE8 for me returns `{ height: NaN, width: NaN, x: NaN, x2: NaN, y: NaN, y2: NaN }` while `path._getBBox()` returns `{height: undefined, width: undefined, x: NaN, y: NaN}`